# How to check remotely if multiple Raspberry Pis are online (or not) without opening ports on multiple routers?

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, remote-access, ping

I'm trying to check if my raspberries are online from outside my home but for security reasons I CANNOT open any port on my routeur.

When I'm on the same network, I just ping them with a PHP script but how can I do it remotely ?

I would like to be able to do it with PHP.

Comment: You could open ICMP port 1, which is what ping uses, which is totally safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create scheduled script (use cron to schedule) which makes request to a web service. Script just informs the web service that "I am alive, don't worry" then you can request from the web service the list of raspberries and their last contact times.

If you can't open any ports, I guess that is the only option. Of course, you need to create that web service or find existing one. For that, you need web server (virtualized or not) which has public IP address (static preferably).

There is example how you can listen requests with PHP below. I assume that you can give unique name to each raspberry device.

```
<?php // myWebService.php
$nameOfDevice = $_GET['name'];
$timestamp = time();

// Here you can save timestamp to database or file or any place you want
saveThings($nameOfDevice, $timestamp);

// Let's just print something out that the scheduled script knows
// that everything went ok
echo 'OK';
?>
```

In raspberry you can use PHP too to make requests to web service: (make sure you have php_curl module installed).

```
#!/usr/bin/php5
// informWebService.php
$deviceName = "device-name-1";
$webServiceUrl = "http://xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq/myWebService.php?name=" . $deviceName;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "My Inform Script / 1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

// Let's set timeout to 10 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Your php might not be located in /usr/bin/php5 so make sure you change that or run that script by typing php informWebService.php. These scripts are just examples and you should edit them to suit better for your solution.

Comment: Thanks ! I have a VPS :) Do you know how I could 'listen' the requests using PHP ?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't open a port on your router, the only way would be to send the traffic the other way: get the Pis to poll something outside your house periodically and check to see when it was last polled.

You should be able to find a way of doing this for free. For instance, you might get them hooked up with your Google Drive account and then use `grive` or `GoogleCL` or a similar Google Drive command line interface to update the timestamp of a file located there. Or, if you have a web site that's in your control outside your home, you could get them to hit a predefined URL, and then get the web server to log such requests.

But, really, it's not unsafe to open a port on your router, as long as you know what you're doing, and your Pis are carefully locked down.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Unfortunately, for legal reasons I cannot open any port :) (it's business related)

Answer (score 0):

If you for what ever reason can't have the Raspberry Pis polling an outsice service, another alternative to actually opening ports to the Pis is to implement a **status service** at the router (or somewhere behind it that you *can* open a port to) that does the pinging and answers to queries by the outside PHP.

Such a service might be as simple as a web page that pings all Pis and then outputs a JSON of which are alive or a more sophisticated proxy that answers to queries about a specific Pi (essentially proxying the ping through the router).

Of course, security is essential here too. You should set up **HTTPS** (self-signed certificate is quite OK for such a service as the only clients to it are under your control). Inside HTTPS, you could use **Basic Auth** or create two **key pairs** and use signed requests between the two PHP services.